# Set bandwidth on TP-Link TD-W8951NB router

Tags: router, ethernet, bandwidth

I have problem with my router. I want to set bandwidth, ie: for port 2, maximal 300 kb/s. How can I do it? I tried google, but everyone has other design of `192.168.1.1` and I don't have there these options. My `192.168.1.1` looks like this:

[image]

Does someone know, where can I set bandwidth in this one? Can you navigate through menu bar, where can I find this option?

**Note**: I don't know a lot in routers. Here I know how to turn on/off WiFi, it's all I was able to do well.

Comment: Most SoHo routers have no ability to set bandwidth by port because all the ports are just connected to a hardware switch.

Comment: And can I set bandwidth globally? If yes, then for example, setting bandwidth to 300 kb/s will set 300 for each port, or maximal bandwidth like slower internet connection?

Comment: You almost certainly cannot set bandwith by port because the portion of the router that controls what packets are send where has no idea which port the packet is going to wind up on. You will get more helpful answers if you explain your problem in as much detail as you can rather than asking for help implementing what you think is the solution to whatever problem you're actually having.

Comment: What I want to get is, that I set 300 kb/s bandwidth. On computer one, someone is downloading some content, or uploading, I don't care, but his maximal speed is 300 kb/s. When I come to computer 2 (and pc 1 is using max speed), I will be able to use internet regularly, because there is still something "free". My max speed is 600 kb/s from ISP. When pc 1 uses 300 kb/s, then another 300 kb/s should left for pc 2. So should I buy another router?

Comment: No, buying another router won't help. Your bandwidth limit is the limit to how much data your ISP can put onto the link to you. Your router has no control over how your ISP fills your pipe. By the time your router receives a packet, the soonest you could do something about it, it's already too late as it has consumed your link bandwidth. See if you can configure bandwidth limiting on the PCs.

Comment: Ok, probably configuring bandwidth on eaach computer will be best way. Thanks for info.